# What do you need to perform Karatsuba multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, products

[Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is usually defined in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and computes
$$(aB^m+b)(cB^m+d)=acB^{2m} +[(a+b)(c+d)-ac-bd]B^m+bd$$ (where B is the base, usually 10) in only three multiplications and a few more additions.

But it turns out you can use this same approach to multiply complex numbers or polynomials. So it seems as long you can express every element of a set as $y=ax+b$ (with some more restrictions on the nature of this elements) you can apply the algorithm.

Now, the question is what must this elements hold? I'd say $a, b \in R$ are elements of a ring, but what properties are necessary for $x$ and its set? What kind of structures does this generate?

Comment: Do you want to know when this formula holds (should be in any ring) or when this formula is useful (e.g., for making multiplication faster)?

Comment: @j.p. Well, that's an interesting point too (I'd say always not thinking it deeply), but I'm currently just asking about the conditions of $x$ and its set.

Comment: The formula holds in any (commutative) ring. You can always choose $a=0$, but the choice of $a$ and $b$ given $x$ and $y$ reminds me of division with rest with remainder and therefore Euclidean rings.

Answer (score 1):

One feature of karatsuba is that $0 \leq a,b,c,d < B$ so the karatsuba formula is close to the digit expansion once you implement the carries.

There are objects called graded rings such as $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ where distribution formula holds and this formula could be helpful.

However the integers arent really graded with respect to the base expansion.  There is some "spillover" due to the carries.

A complex generalization could be have $|a |,|b|,|c|,|d|<B$ for some radius $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure I have completely understood your answer, but I can't see how to extend that inequality to the complex numbers or the polynomials -- I think it's not a "requirement" any more